# AngularJS upgrade 1.2 to 1.5

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, dependency-injection, migration

I am currently upgrading an Angular 1.2.x application to 1.5.5. After upgrading it, the application itself is still working fine. Unfortunately my servicetests are failing with (e.g) the errormessage:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: storeProvider <- store <- secondService

As far as i understand the previous errormessage it is telling me, that within the testscope there is no 'secondService' available. I considered that to be the

Let's say 'firstService' must be mocked. The second service is so simple that it is not needed to mock it.

```
describe('mainService', function () {
  [...]
  beforeEach(module('app.myApp', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$state', stateMock);
    $provide.value('firstService', firstServiceMock);
    //following line is needed in Angular 1.3 and greater,
    //if i am running it on angular 1.2 without the line it is working
    $provide.value('secondService', secondServiceMock); }));

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
mainService = $injector.get('mainService');
```

How can i inject the original 'secondService' into my unittest, as i do not want to mock every service that this servicetest is depending on.

Please correct me if i am wrong, as i understood it is an issue with scoping https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3. But this more looks like it is related to controllers and not to services.

If it is, then how can i inject it? I also could not figure out a way to use the deprecated mentioned '$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();' in the testcontext.
The Class:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app.myApp').factory('mainService', mainService);

/* ngInject */
function mainService($state, firstService, secondService,){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is found in here. I could not see the whole context, so this question should be ignored. 
[Bower dependency found in unit test Angular 1.2, but cannot be found Angular 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294411/bower-dependency-found-in-unit-test-angular-1-2-but-cannot-be-found-angular-1-5)